# Php oracle multi database Query

Tags: php, oracle

Normaly  if mysql or mssql i would do like below
Database A : test1
Database B : test2
Database C : test3

Sql Statement :

```
select * FROM test1.table1  
join test2  on test1.table1.id  = test2.table2.id
join test3  on test1.table1.id  = test3.table4.id
```

How it work in Oracle and Php ?

Comment: I guess it won't work in oracle until you'll get a database links. 'Cause there could be only one database per instance in oracle.

Comment: got any example? with database link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you need to create a database link in oracle at first:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK dblink_name 
   CONNECT TO username IDENTIFIED BY password
   USING 'service_name';
```

Service_name is a record in your database's tnsnames.ora.

Or, if you don't want to use tnsnames.ora, you can specify your net name right in create function, like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK dblink_name 
     CONNECT TO username IDENTIFIED BY password
     USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA(SID=dbname))';
```

and then use it this way:

```
SELECT host_name, instance_nmame FROM v$instance@dblink_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

have you try it exactly the same way in PHP with MySQL?

```
<?php

$sql_statement = "SELECT
    PostID,
    AuthorID,
    Users.tblUsers.Username
    FROM tblPosts
    LEFT JOIN Users.tblUsers ON AuthorID = Users.tblUsers.UserID
    GROUP BY PostID,AuthorID,Username
    ";

$dblink = mysql_connect("somehost", "someuser", "password");
mysql_select_db("BlogPosts",$dblink);
$qry = mysql_query($sql_statement,$dblink);

?>
```